# Caddy reverse_proxy with websocket JSON config

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I have this simple caddy JSON config to proxy request from https://localhost to my localhost server running on port 8080. That's working fine.

```
{
    "apps": {
        "http": {
            "servers": {
                "localhost": {
                    "listen": [":443"],
                    "routes": [
                        {
                            "match": [
                                {
                                    "host": ["localhost"]
                                }
                            ],
                            "handle": [
                                {
                                    "handler": "reverse_proxy",
                                    "upstreams": [
                                        {
                                            "dial": "localhost:8080"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, I would also like my caddy server to either:

- reverse proxy calls from `wss:localhost:3000/ws` to `ws:localhost:3000/ws` (HTTPS to HTTP)
- or simply ignore websocket calls and let them reach `ws:localhost:3000/ws`

I have not found the proper example or documentation for JSON config.

Comment: did you got it working ? if yes,, pls share the new config..

Answer (score 0):

Check if [Caddy 2.5](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/releases/tag/v2.5.0) (Apr. 2022) could help in your use case.

It comes with **Reverse proxy: Dynamic upstreams**:

> The ability to get the list of upstreams at every request (more specifically, every iteration in the proxy loop of every request) rather than just once at config-load time.
>
> Dynamic upstream modules can be plugged in to provide Caddy with the latest list of backends in real-time.
> Two standard modules have been implemented which can get upstreams from `SRV` and `A/AAAA` record lookups.
>
> Warning: This deprecates the `lookup_srv` JSON field for upstreams (and `srv+` scheme prefix in the Caddyfile), which will be removed in the future.

See [PR 4470](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/pull/4470):

> Right now, proxy upstreams have to be hard-coded into the config (with the only dyanamism coming from placeholders, which all act as a single upstream anyway).
>
> This change adds supports for truly dynamic upstreams, with the potential for every request to have different upstreams -- not only every request, but every retry within a single request, too.
>
> Instead of (or in addition to) specifying upstreams in your config, you could specify dynamic_upstreams and then define your upstream source module. Currently I'm implementing SRV and A/AAAA lookups as sources.